Hibernate 6.4 override @SoftDelete restriction to retrieve all the records
I used Hibernate @SoftDelete annotation in one of Entity to enable soft delete feature.
I need to retrieve all the records for one of the use-cases.
I tried using JPA Specifications, custom query, and native query as well. But all these attempts I saw
and deleted=false

restriction is always automatically adds to the query. Hence I can't retrieve all the records regardless of deleted state.
How can I achieve this?

You can try @SQLSelect annotation on the related entity.
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name1")
public class TableName1{
    ..............

    @JoinColumn(name = "tb2_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TableName2 tableName2;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name2")
@SQLSelect(sql = "SELECT * from table_name2 WHERE id = ?") // <-- This part is the solution
public class TableName2{
............
}

Interestingly, this annotation does not affect your find methods, but your relations will start using annotated SQL.

If I get it correctly, your suggestion is with @SQLSelect in the entity level will override this @SoftDelete effect. Is it? @Yusuf

Yes, Did you try it? It worked for my case.

Yes it did @Yusuf. Thanks for your time!
